# Running A Phonegap Application as A Service On Android

Tags: android, service, cordova

I'm attempting to use phonegap/cordova to develop an application that contains a music player.  I would like the music to continue to play in the background after the application has lost focus.  From the research I've done it appears that the only way to accomplish this on the Android platform is to run the media operations from a service.

Unfortunately, Phonegap doesn't provide any javascript hooks to do this (which makes sense since that would be device specific functionality).  I'm looking for ways to leverage the phonegap API but allow the music to play in the background on Android. Any ideas?

Comment: If I had to guess, you will have to settle for implementing the UI of your music player in PhoneGap and implement the player itself in Java code as a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to come up with an Android service (ie java and/or ndk) to handle the background playing, and trigger it from the javascript/html used under phonegap.

There are a variety of ways you could make that interaction - I'm going to suggest them in overview, actual implementation may require some additional steps.

- You can register custom java methods making them accessible to the javascript program, these could be wrappers for ordinary android activity-service interaction.
- You could setup a custom intent URL which your player (or something fronting for it) is registered with the platform to handle and trigger that with hyperlinks in the document
- You could have an android service that listens on a local socket and contact that from the javascript (you may require extensions to phonegap in order to do so)

Comment: I was afraid that I would have to do something custom. This kind of cuts down on some of the advantages of using Phonegap for me, but it's probably still worth it.

Comment: I doubt it's going to be that bad.  If html/javascript is still attractive to you as a way to build the UI, then it should only take an extra day at most to learn how to get things connected up for javascript-java interaction (vs an all java solution - you would still need an Android service and the activity-service interaciton either way).  And you can probably abstract out the android uniqueness of this and replace it with whatever is appropriate for another platform if you want to keep your UI side portable.